# XML with Cocoa Touch

Tags: iphone, xml, cocoa-touch

I am a new learner at the area of Objective-C. I would like to retrieve data from XML page on the iPhone. Is it possible? It would be more helpful to me if I get an appropriate suggestion or code.

Answer (score 2):

The SDK comes with the [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class. Some people prefer to use the [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/) library as it can be faster and more memory efficient than NSXMLDocument but you may want to wrap it with an Objective C layer as it is a C API. See this [example](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html).

Comment: No NSXMLDocument in the iphone sdk, it only has NSXMLParser.

Answer (score 2):

There was a good episode of cocoaFusion: the other day that covered the ins and outs of XML parsing.  Head on over to [cocoafusion.net](http://cocoafusion.net/files/category-episodes.html) and look for Episode 2: An intro to using web APIs and XML.

The show notes section for that episode has some sample code downloads and links to other sites that contain more information (including some of the links mentioned in the other answers here).

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

A good article that lays out how you can use NSXMLParser to rip through xml.

[Parsing XML in Cocoa](http://weblog.bignerdranch.com/?p=48)

Answer (score 0):

There is also some other libraries: TouchXML, KissXML.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the SiesmicXML tute on Apple's iPhone developer site. It uses the XMLParser in a dedicated thread to parse XML in a backgroud process.

JK